# Max Mega Menu Wordpress: Cambia color en item de mega menu cuando hago hover sobre otro item

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, style

Estoy tratando de cambiar el color de un item de un Mega Menu cuando hago hover en otro item diferente. En la imagen se ve la idea de lo que necesito.

[image: Ideal function]

Usé estos CSS pero no funcionó:

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link { 
    color: #85918f;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link { 
    color: white;
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Estoy usando el plugin Max Mega Menu

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Intenta agregar !important al final de los estilos, por ejemplo, "color: #85918f!important;"

Comment: Gracias, sigue sin funcionar creo que mas bien se trata mas bien de identificar cuales clases debo tocar cuando haga hover en un elemento, pero sigo sin dar con ello

Comment: Tienes algun enlace para compartir, posiblemente los selectores sean incorrectos, aun asi, estoy muy seguro que el plugin debe de tener un apartado para hacerlo sin codigo

Comment: Si claro, el sitio es este [enlace]https://act-alliance.development.humanitarian.tech/ .Según el soporte del plugin es un tipo de customización que no hacen por default y se requiere de personalizar los estilos (aunque no ayudan como)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente encontré la solución. Si alguién mas necesita lo mismo les dejo por aqui el código:

```
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link,  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row > ul.mega-sub-menu:hover > li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
    color: #85918f;
}

#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:hover li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-row > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-column > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item:hover > a.mega-menu-link  { 
    color: white !important;
}
```

Saludos